# Typescript - Using interfaces with third party API's

Tags: typescript

I can use `interfaces` to declare the data types that go in and the return values out of a function
but if that function calls an external API, does the `interface` do anything?

Typescript can only tell me errors before compilation/run time
how do you pair typescript with something like a try catch block or error logging in general?
*(to get the most out of typescript features)*

Comment: Are you asking about using TypeScript to perform runtime validation of data? I think that's not the original intentions of it.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers from friends:

answer:

No it doesn’t do anything to prevent errors from the outside world. What you would typically do is use type guards when retrieving data from the outside world and if the type guards pass then you can safely say that your data is the shape of your interface. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts can help